# How to avoid an image from occurring as thumbnail on sharing

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, facebook-graph-api

Hi I wish to avoid my [sites logo images](http://gk-hunger-games.blogspot.uk) from showing up as a thumbnail on being shared on social networks. One thing that I know that to avoid an image from occurring as a thumbnail one can use css sprites or data uri's but I also want the logo image to show up in search results. Is there a way to get this done? Scripts or any special markups are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should view this post about open graph markup where you determine which image to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5749028/how-do-i-prevent-an-image-from-showing-up-as-a-thumbnail-option-when-my-site-is

Answer (score 0):

Don't use it as image, use it as background of a div.

CSS

```
#logo{
background: url('http://gk-hunger-games.blogspot.uk/logo.png');
width: 250px;
height: 60px;
}
#logolink{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="logo">
   <a id="logolink" href="http://gk-hunger-games.blogspot.uk"> </a>
</div>
```